# Class attributes in Eiffel

Tags: class, eiffel, void-safety

I am trying to make a class in Eiffel, consisting of a few attributes and functions. I keep getting issues with the attributes not being either visible to setName or not being initialised correctly. The compiler error is: VEVI: Variable is not properly set. Attribute(s): name.   I want to be able to instantiate a TESTER object in APPLICATION and invoke these methods.

```
class
    TESTER
create
    make

feature

    name: STRING
    score: INTEGER
    make

        do
            io.putstring ("I am making TESTER%N")
        end

        sleep
        do
            io.put_string ("TESTER is sleeping%N")
        end

        setName (name_: STRING)
        do
            name := name_
        end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with **void-safety** ( https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffel/Void-safe%20programming%20in%20Eiffel ).

There are several ways to address the issue in the example, two of them are shown below:

1. Declare `name` as `detachable`. By default class types are `attached`. Changing the type to `detachable` allows the attribute `name` to be initialized to the default value `Void`, i.e. not attached to any object.

   ```
   name: detachable STRING
   ```
2. Attach an object to the attribute `name` in the creation procedure `make`.

   ```
   make
       do
           io.putstring ("I am making TESTER%N")
           name := "something"
       end
   ```

The simplified version of the rule says that ***all attributes should be set at the end of a creation procedure***.